# Problem Regarding Delays in Notification in Android

Tags: android

how can i give a delay in Notification in Android? My notification is coming just pressing ok Button.
please help soon.
Mayank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to a view (like your button) you can just use [View.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can start an AsyncTask (or a Timer and Timertask, or just a Thread) that delays (using `Thread.sleep`) and then fires the notification. You don't want to sleep on the UI thread, which is why you need a separate thread of some sort.